# C# timer backgroundworker user controls

Tags: c#, timer, user-controls, backgroundworker

I have a C# Windows Form Application that has a menu called Start Download Files and thi menu have then two instantiated user controls(submenu, tab menus).
For each tab (user control) i have a download button and a timer that runs it every 5 minutes.
I am using a private background worker which is created every time the control loads and runs a method to start download the files. That gives me a lot of troubles which i still can't find a solution for because:
- when i enable the timer for both controls they start the download multiple times for each and i get into concurrency accessing the files or
- cross thread exceptions

Does someone experienced something similar and maybe can give me a hint?

My code looks like this:

```
 public partial class ucGeneralInfo : UserControl
    {
      private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

      private void TimerDownloadFrequency_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Branch);

            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Download_Process((string) e.Argument);
        }

        private void Download_Process(string Branch)
        {
         // copying files
         // processing files
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use _TPL DataFlow_?

Comment: The issue is that i have same control instantiated twice and the threads there are mixing ...

Answer (score 0):

For concurrent access, use `lock`.

```
 lock(fileLock)
 {
     wc.DownloadFileAsync (/*...*/);
 }
```

For `Cross-thread exception` use `Invoke` .

```
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
      timer.Enable = true;
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm curious what's wrong in my code that make the backgroundworker to run twice or more for the same control either that is created new every time? About the lock i see this as a workaround and not as a solution, the solution will be to run once.

Comment: Maybe I understand your problem. What is you do only one backgroundworker, outside your tabs. And then only one bg worker will work, if it is busy, others can't download till it doesn't end, won't happend concurrent file acces.